# How to count the number of rows in a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, primefaces, datatable

I can't seem to find this anywhere. I have a dataTable like [this one](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf), and I want to be able to count the number of rows in the dataTable in javascript. how would that be accomplished? thanks!

I need it in javascript because I want to iterate through the datatable and check to see if any rows cantain certain data in them.

**EXAMPLE PSEUDOCODE**

```
var tableSize = someway to get table size;
for (i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
if (dataTable.row(i).value == "someValue") {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: INMO you really better reconsider doing that logic on server side...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would be easier to count the rows with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
var tableSize = $('#myTable tbody tr').length;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YLVuK/1/

Comment: Question is asking how to do it in `Javascript` though.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you could simply do

```
var tableSize = $("#myTable").find("tbody").find("td").length;
```

And name your table with an ID of "myTable"

Comment: Good catch - change <td> to <tr>

Answer (score 0):

if your table has an id, you can do it as follows:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
for(var i = 0, ceiling = table.rows.length; i < ceiling; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i]; // this gets you every row
    for(var j = 0, ceiling2 = row.cells[j]; j < ceiling2; j++) {
        var cell = row.cells[j]; // this gets you every cell of the current row in the loop
        var cellContent = cell.innerHTML; // this gets you the content of the current cell in the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of rows in a datatable on the server side in your backing bean and then set a java object attribute equal to the number of rows. Then in your view, you can set the javascript variable using el expression language. Something like this:

Backing bean:

```
public class backer() {
    List<Cars> cars = new ArrayList<Cars>();

    public List<Cars> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public void setCars(List<Cars> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    public int numCars() {
        return cars.size();
    }
}
```

In your xhtml file:

```
var tableSize = #{backer.numCars}
```